# Proof that if $f$ is $n$ times differentiable at $x_0$, then there is also a neighbourhood of $x_0$ where it is $n-1$ times differentiable.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I want to prove that if $f:D\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ is $n$ times differentiable at $x_0$ then there is also has a neighbourhood of $x_0$ where all the functions are $n-1$ times differentiable. And I want to show it by induction. I have set up a proof but as the title suggests I am having trouble finishing it.

---

The limit of a function, i.e. ,$\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}f(x),$ where $x_0$ might or might not be in the domain is motivated by the definition of accumulation points.

An accumulation point of the domain of a function $f$ is a point where every neighbourhood contains infinitely many points in the domain.

If $x_0$ is not in the domain and not an accumulation point, then a function $F$ which assigns a value to this point and is in every other Point defined as the previous function $f$ is continuous in $x_0.$

$(*)$We say $\lim_{x\rightarrow y_0} f(x)$ exists if and only if $x_0$ is in an accumulation point and not in the Domain of the function or in the Domain of the function and if it is possible to assign a value to $x_0$ for $F$ which is defined in the same manner as before such that $x_0$ is continuous in $F$.

---

$(1)$For the base case of my induction I assume there exists a Point in $x_0$ which is $2$ times differentiable in $f$. I think I have to choose $2$ because otherwise it would not make sense to call it a higher-order Derivative.

$(2)$I set up a proof by contradiction by assuming at the same time that there exists no neighbourhood around $x_0$ which is $1-$time differentiable or also just differentiable.

The strategy is to prove that given these circumstances $x_0$ is not an accumulation point in the Domain of $f'$ which would be a contradiction to $(1)$ because for the existence of such a Limit a necessary condition is that $x_0$ is a accumulation point $(*)$.

By $(1)$:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}\frac{f^{'}(x_0)-f^{'}(x)}{x_0-x}\text{ exists}$$

By $(2)$

$$\text{Define: } \delta_0\text{-neighbourhood around }x_0:=N(\delta_0)=\{x\in D:|x-x_0|<\delta_0\}$$

$$\forall_{\delta_{0}\in\mathbb{R}}\exists_{x'_0\in D}\exists_{\epsilon>0}\forall_{\delta>0}\exists_{x\in D}:x'_0\in N(\delta_0)\wedge |x'_0-x|<\delta\wedge \frac{f^{'}(x'_0)-f^{'}(x)}{x'_0-x}\geq\epsilon$$

$$\text{Define: } N'(\delta_0)=\{x\in D:x \text{ is differentiable }\wedge x\in N(\delta_0)\}$$

If I could show there exists a $\delta_0>0$ such that $N'(\delta_0)=\{x_0\}.$ I would be done, but how can I prove this? Please help me.

Comment: Except for wanting to do it by induction (no reason for that), duplicate of  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3106249/a-question-about-a-necessary-condition-for-higher-order-derivates-in-a-point-x/3106257#3106257

Comment: You have said that the Limit can not exists unless $f^{n-1}$ exists  is some neighbourhood of $x_0$. Can you please explain why this is true?

Comment: Do you know the _definition_ of a limit?

Comment: $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}\frac{f^{'}(x_0)-f^{'}(x)}{x_0-x}\text{ exists}\iff \exists_{a\in\mathbb{C}}\forall_{\epsilon>0}\exists_{\delta>0}\forall_{x\in D}|x-x_0|<\delta\Rightarrow |\frac{f^{'}(x_0)-f^{'}(x)}{x_0-x}-a|<\epsilon$

Comment: No I think I have not understood it please tell me why the Definition verrifies the Statement : the Limit can not exists unless$ f^{n−1}  $ exists is some neighbourhood of $ x_0$

Comment: If something is less than $\epsilon$ it must exist. (For example, $|\ln(0)-c|<\epsilon$ cannot possibly be true, since there's no such thing as $\ln(0)$.)

Comment: I don't understand this logic if there's no such Thing as $ln(0)$ it is not a Statement because it can not be true nor false. That's how I am thinking About this

Comment: Right,  $|\ln(0)-c|<\epsilon$ is not a statement, fine. So in particular it is not a _true statement_. In the definition of the derivative that inequality _is_ a true statment, hence that fraction must be defined.

Comment: Wait I have though About it: If something is smaller then $\epsilon$ it umplicates that the something is a number which exists. But if there is no neighbourhood around $x_0$ which is $f^{'}$ this again implicates that we have: $|x-x_0|<\delta\Rightarrow |\frac{f^{'}(x_0)-f^{'}(x)}{x_0-x}-a|<\epsilon$ and also a $b\in \{x\in D:|x-x_0|<\delta\}: f^{'}(b)$ does not exists. Than $|\frac{f^{'}(x_0)-f^{'}(b)}{x_0-b}-a|$ does not exist in contradiction to that it exists. If this is correct than this is not obvious in my eyes.

Comment: What's obvious varies from person  to person...

Comment: Okey I think that means the proof is correct. Thank you for sticking out with me